# Scala REPL in Emacs

Tags: scala, emacs, read-eval-print-loop

I like to do my Scala development in Emacs, and from time to time, I use the REPL to test out snippets of code or to load and test some code I've just written.  I'm using Scala 2.9.1, and I've noticed that when I open the REPL in a terminal buffer, things are substantially broken.  In particular, I am unable to remove any characters from the current line, and cannot move the cursor backward on the current line.  This is highly frustrating as any time I mistype something, I have to begin the command anew.  I was wondering if anyone else is having this problem using the Scala REPL under Emacs, and if anyone has a potential solution.

Comment: How are you starting the REPL within Emacs?

Comment: I open a new buffer with ansi-term.  Then, in that terminal buffer, I start the REPL by calling "scala" directly or using sbt console.  Either way, this problem seems to occur.

Comment: You may have better luck opening a new buffer with shell, and starting scala or sbt from the shell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I find that [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/#rlwrap) (readline wrapper) plays well with emacs' ansi-term and scala. Just call "rlwrap scala", and you'll have the usual bash line editing, as well as history, working properly. As a bonus, your history will span multiple invocations of scala, so you won't lose everything you've typed after exiting the Scala REPL.

If rlwrap doesn't work for you, just switching to line-mode in ansi-term (C-x C-j by default) will allow you to use emacs-style editing on the line, but without the shell niceties like history and completion.

Ensime has already been mentioned, so I'll just second that as a great option if you don't mind the setup involved.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  This seems to work pretty well for me.  In fact, I like the rlwrap approach over the Ensime approach because it gives me a command history.  Right now, the only remaining limitation to invoking the REPL via Emacs using the rlwrap approach is an inability to use tab-completion.

Comment: How did you get tab-completion in the REPL through emacs?

Answer (score 9):

You may install [ENSIME](https://github.com/ensime/) and [follow instructions](http://ensime.github.io/). I don't know about your way to invoke REPL, but REPL called from ENSIME works (it allows moving the cursor backward and deleting symbols, I've checked).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  It looks like invoking the REPL from Ensime does solve this problem, but it introduces a few others.  In particular, the REPL invoked via Ensime doesn't have a command history, and doesn't seem capable of tab-completion.

Comment: @nomad: they made tab-completion work. See http://ensime.github.io/editors/emacs/userguide/#code-completion.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [ammonite repl](http://ammonite.io/#Ammonite-REPL), `amm`. I can confirm tab completion works in the emacs `ansi-term`. This is true for its default mode (based on stty) or [you can use JLine3](http://ammonite.io/#Configuration) with `amm`. Note that the Dotty (tentative Scala 3) repl, `dotr`, is also based on `amm` and also has working tab-completion in `ansi-term`.